# Python Парсинг, обработка ошибки

Tags: python, парсер

Как обработать данную ошибку:

> urllib.error.URLError: <­urlopen error [WinError 10060] Попытка
>   установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за
>   требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже
>   установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного
>   компьютера>

Просто еще не знаю как точно работает try и except. Тем не менее реализовать свою задачу все-таки хочется. Сразу скажу, что с соединением все в порядке.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/urllib2.html#urlerror

Comment: Вообще, это может быть из-за того, что сайт блокирует подобные программные запросы